# Laravel Eloquent Query Using WHERE a set of conditions or OR another set of conditions along with some common conditions?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have to do a sql operation in my Laravel project.

along with the mentioned conditions I have some common conditions.  I know how to write it in raw mysql.

so, for example 
What I need Is

How do I say `WHERE Condition X AND Condition Y AND ( (a = 1 and b =1 ) OR (c = 1 AND d = 1) )`  using laravel query format ?

Comment: You can use this documentation to understand more about How to build query in Laravel.  https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#where-clauses

Comment: the where method can accep an anonymous function, and within it groups it accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following syntax:

```
DB::table('yourTable')
    ->where('x', '=', '1')
    ->where('y', '=', '1')
    ->where(function($q1)
    {
        $q1->where(function($q2)
        {
            $q2->where('a', '=', '1')
            ->where('b', '=', '1');
        })
        ->orWhere(function($q2)
        {
            $q2->where('c', '=', '1')
            ->where('d', '=', '1');
        });
    });
```

If you prefer More Readable Syntax `where` will accept the array as Argument

```
DB::table('yourTable')
            ->where('x','=',1)
            ->where('y','=',1)
            ->where(function($queryBuilder){
                $queryBuilder->where([
                    ['a','=',1],
                    ['b','=',1],
                ])
                ->orWhere([
                    ['c','=',1],
                    ['d','=',1],
                ]);
            });
```

Comment: I have a condition E and condition F both are common for for all situation. How to implement it too ?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to group them separately by using closures. `orWhere()` for the outer query, and `where()` for the inner ones.

```
$a = 1;
$b = 1;
$c = 1;
$d = 1;

Model::where(function($query) use ($a, $b) {
        $query->where("a", $a)
              ->where("b", $b);
    })
    ->orWhere(function($query) use ($c, $d) {
        $query->where("c", $c)
              ->where("d", $d);
    });
```

If you don't have a model, you can replace `Model::` by `DB::table("myTable")`.

You can use `toSql()` to see the final query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = DB::table(...)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('a', 1)->where('b', 1);
    })->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('c', 1)->where('d, 1);
    });
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Query Builder - Where Clauses - Parameter Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#parameter-grouping)